# Checkmarx issue : Heap Inspection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, checkmarx

Checkmarx complains "Method changePassword defines oldPassword, which is designated to contain user passwords. However, while plaintext passwords are later assigned to oldPassword, this variable is never cleared from memory. It this a false positive?

```
@PutMapping(path = "/changepassword", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> changePassword(@RequestBody UserUpdate user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
    String uid= user.getId();
    String oldPassword = user.getOldPwrd();
    String newPassword = user.getPwrd();
    userDetails.changeUserPassword(uid, oldPassword, newPassword);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: No, but there may not be much you can do about it. A best practice is to use char[] instead of String for passwords, as the characters can be modified after use. A String on the other hand remains as-is on the heap, so if someone can get a heap dump they can steal it. If you can change to char[] everywhere that would be better, but if the password is stored in a String at least once the damage has been done. Or if you use char[] without wiping the contents, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered as a best security practice to not store passwords in immutable strings and use an encrypted memory object such as [SealedObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html). This specialized class can store encrypted data in memory and helps ensure that it can't be easily retrieved from memory.

```
@PutMapping(path = "/changepassword", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> changePassword(@RequestBody UserUpdate user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  {
    String uid= user.getId();
    SealedObject oldPassword = user.getOldPwrd();
    SealedObject newPassword = user.getPwrd();
    userDetails.changeUserPassword(uid, oldPassword, newPassword);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(SUCCESS);
}
```

You will have to change your changeUserPassword method to handle SealedObject which involves defining a cipher and key for encryption:

```
Key key = getKeyFromConfiguration();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_NAME);
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
List<Character> characterList = Arrays.asList(input);
password = new SealedObject((Serializable) characterList, c);
Arrays.fill(input, '\0');
```